# I'm trying to fetch members from a guild using their ID but now the variable I'm using returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

All this was working fine an hour ago but now discord.js refuses to fetch members from a guild using their ID.

```
let target = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

And I have not changed anything at all from when it was working.
I have no idea how this could occur but I'm confused as hell.

***Note***: `args[0]` is a string. A user ID from the first argument in a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it worked. There is no `.fetch()` method on the `.cache` property and it returns a promise so you need to `await` the member:

```js
let target = await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
```

[image]