# How to show roles of a mentioned user in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a profile command for discord. It needs to show the roles of a user. I know how to show roles of message author but the same method for showing roles of message author doesn't work for pinged members.

I'll show my code to make it more clear:

```js
// this one works as expected
message.member.roles.cache.map((role) => role.name).join(", ")
```

```js
// but this one doesn't work
let pingedUser = message.mentions.users.first(); 
pingedUser.roles.cache.map((role) => role.name).join(", ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one works because it maps the roles of a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). The second one doesn't work because you try to get the roles of a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), but only `GuildMember`s have roles.

To fix this, you can use `message.mentions.members.first()` instead as [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) returns a `GuildMember`:

```js
let pingedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

pingedMember.roles.cache.map((role) => role.name).join(', ');
```

Comment: Btw do you know how to do this with id? Like instead of mentioning, using id to see roles?

Comment: Sure, you can fetch a member by their ID, this one might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66176807/6126373